# Why won't the average column amount not calculate?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, 2d

I want to print out the average amount of an 2D array column, by filling the matrix with random numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int array[m][n];
    double ran_num = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    double avg_col[] = {0};
    
    printf("Enter (m, n > 0): ");
    scanf("%d, %d", &m, &n);
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i <= m; ++i){
        for(size_t j = 0; j <= n; ++j){
            array[i][j] = ran_num;
            avg_col[j] += array[i][j] / m;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Average of column %d : %.3f\n", i ,avg_col[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is:

```
Average of column 0 : 0.000
Average of column 1 : 0.000
Average of column 2 : 0.000
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.
Maybe you can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Remember that arrays in C are *not* dynamic. You define `avg_col` as an array of *one single* element. And what's worse, you define `array` with *zero* elements, which isn't allowed at all. And once you fix all that your loops will have a one-off error and go out of bounds. And you should probably be getting new random numbers inside the loop, or all values will be the same.

Comment: To summarize: There are so many basic errors that you seem to have skipped pretty large parts of your books, tutorials or classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
avg_col[j] += array[i][j] / m;
```

variable `array[i][j]` is an integer, and variable `m` is an integer.
So you are doing integer division.  If the denominator `m` is greater than the numerator `array[i][j]`, then the result is ZERO.

Example:

```
5 / 10; // Humans think the result is 0.5.  Programmers know the result is 0.
```

Comment: So, if you are building something circular you would be using 3 for the value of pi...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed up for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    
    printf("Enter (m, n > 0): ");
    scanf("%d, %d", &m, &n);
    
    double array[m][n];
    double avg_col[n];
    memset(avg_col, 0, sizeof(avg_col));
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            array[i][j] = ((double)rand()) / RAND_MAX;
            avg_col[j] += (double)array[i][j] / m;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Average of column %d : %.3f\n", i ,avg_col[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output (with input `5, 10`)

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5460KB
Enter (m, n > 0): 5, 10
Average of column 0 : 0.475
Average of column 1 : 0.575
Average of column 2 : 0.460
Average of column 3 : 0.661
Average of column 4 : 0.588
Average of column 5 : 0.478
Average of column 6 : 0.480
Average of column 7 : 0.697
Average of column 8 : 0.356
Average of column 9 : 0.620
```